# Call to a member function setId() on a non-object in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Call to a member function setId() on a non-object in

and here is my code

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$model = Mage::getModel('catelog/product');
for($id=1;$id<4;$id++)

  echo "in loop";
// Mage::init();


try 
  {
    $model->setId($id)->delete();
    echo "Data deleted successfully.";
  } 
    catch (Exception $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

how i solve this prob please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catelog/product');
```

To

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

To delete a product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->delete();
```